# similar to lightbox plugin that also fits (shrinks) the image to the screen

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I tried with the various lightbox plugins for wordpress but they don't resize the image to fit the screen.. is there any that do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try Fancybox. I use it on my own site and it definitely gets the job done.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fancybox-for-wordpress/